# css is not applied after print

Tags: asp.net, html, css, c#-4.0

i have dynamically created table with string builder..

when i run this page background color is applied to 'th' but when print the page it doesnt print background color. But when i applied font color to 'th' then it prints font color after printing..

```
StringBuilder strhtmlcontent = new StringBuilder();
strhtmlcontent.Append("<table id='mytable' align='Center' style='background-color:#' BORDER-COLLAPSE:collapse cellSpacing=0 rules=all border=1 width=100% ><th width=8% style='background-color:Lime;'>FirstName</th>");
strhtmlcontent.Append("</table>");
ttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strhtmlcontent);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Thanks.

Comment: By default, browsers won't print background colors. It's by design of the browsers and got nothing to do with programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a background image to print using css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949897/how-to-get-a-background-image-to-print-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below link:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t162435-keeping-background-colors-in-printing.html