# how to print div with picture background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a background image to print using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949897/how-to-get-a-background-image-to-print-using-css)

i have a div that has a picture background

```
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>
<div style='background:url(name.png);width:100px; height:100px;'></div>
<input type='button' onclick='window.print()'>//button that print

 </body>

 </html>
```

it works fine when i view it in browsers..but the moment that i print the page with div it doesnt print the  background picture... but does print the text and image declared in

how could i fixed this ???

Comment: You should add `print` css: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596876/how-can-i-print-background-images-in-ff-or-ie

Comment: You're also supposed to do [your own research](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=print+background+image) first.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **StyleSheet media = print** and than you can try

```
@media print {
   div {font-size: 10pt; line-height: 120%; background: white;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers by default do not print background images. More often than not the pictures get in the way of reading the text.

So, we'll assume you have a good reason. Your design is so super awesome that it needs to be printed or something. Maybe you are creating a e-ticket stub and the text overlays the template image. Let's go with that.

To defeat the default action of having background images not print, I would simply not have my image as a background. I would let it be a regular html element and use either CSS and/or JavaScript to layer the image under your text. Look at the position and z-index CSS properties.

Your old problem is gone, good luck with the new problems this may create.