# Background colors on Oracle Apex report not displaying when printing

Tags: css, oracle, printing, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a printer-friendly page in an application in APEX 4.2. Currently, my printer-friendly page displays a report that includes alternating blue and white rows. Additionally, I have a blue background behind my column headers. When I print the page, everything shows up perfectly except for the background colors. Has anyone been able to resolved a similar experience? If not, do you know if this is a CSS issue or possibly some setting in APEX that I may have overlooked?

Comment: When I use the "Print" function in Chrome, it offers an option to print "Background colours and images", by default it is turned off. Maybe you need to turn that option on.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for some of the background colors on my page. Do you know if there is a way to color my rows without them being considered "background colors"? I am concerned my users may not know to turn that option on.

Comment: You could start diving into the world of media queries http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2014/07/apex-printer-friendly-pages-with-css-media-queries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print background images
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16322665/527513

eg, for chrome:

```
#p1_static_region_id {-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}
```