# Using div class to contain an image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, header

Hey guys i have a HTML/CSS related question here...

I'm developing on a salesforce application, which makes me use this apex tag to put images in and I'm not really comfortable with using them. I am making print layouts at the moment for some forms that i've created. Everything worked fine until i had 2 images that i needed to style differently. I have 1 image in the header and 1 image that is a box within the form. Since i am styling the image in the header with some padding and centering among other stuff...the other box image wont show up as i go to print. So i was wondering if i can just separate the header image via a div tag. Here is what i have so far....

HTML:

```
<div class="logo_print"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .logo_print{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 86px;
    background-image:url('../css_images/seal2.png');
}
```

So this is the header image i put in a div tag...did not work but if anyone has any thoughts/solutions that would be great....been trying out a bunch of diff ways with no progress. Thanks

EDIT:
So I've put new CSS in with some recommendations..so now i see it on my website but when i go to print the forms...the image does not show up :/

OH and i am using @media print to put the CSS in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason it's not working is because you haven't specified a height and width in your css.

**Try This:**

```css
.logo {
  background-image: url('http://pixelative.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/logo2.png');
  width: 209px;
  height: 52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Here's a codepen of the [working example](http://codepen.io/arslanhawn/pen/myaRBg).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: ok so this worked for it coming up on my web site....but when i go to print it the image does not show up....any ideas? i updated with my new code

Comment: you can show it in safari or chrome by using 
`@media print {
   * {-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}
}`

for other browsers, i'm afraid you'd need to use an 'img' tag in html. For further reading please check out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949897/how-to-get-a-background-image-to-print-using-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949897/how-to-get-a-background-image-to-print-using-css)